# SolvePnP works unstable and crashes

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to implement `solvePnP` to find extrinsic parameters of the camera. I detect some points on the image with known 3d position and feed 2 sets of points to `solvePnP`.

With some set of points function works very accurate but very often when I add or remove some points from the set the solution becomes totally incorrect. Actually it takes a lot of efforts to find what set of points is good for `solvePnP`.

Detected points are not very accurate (+- `10` pixels from true position) - can it be a reason? But still with some sets it works perfectly.

And another problem is that `SolvePnPRansac` and `SolvePnP` with `CV_P3P` parameter crashes throwing memory exception.

Here is my code

```
vector<cv::Point3d> points3d;
vector<cv::Point2d> points2d;
cv::Mat rvec(3,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar::all(0)) , tvec(3,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar::all(0));        
Mat cam_matrix = Mat(3,3,CV_64FC1,Scalar::all(0)); 
cam_matrix.at<double>(0,0) = 395.;
cam_matrix.at<double>(0,2) = 160.;
cam_matrix.at<double>(1,1) = 395.;
cam_matrix.at<double>(1,2) = 120.;
cam_matrix.at<double>(2,2) = 1.0f;



 /*
here is a code for pushing 3d and 2d points to points3d and points2d vectors
*/

cv::solvePnP(points3d, points2d, cam_matrix, Mat(), rvec, tvec, false, CV_ITERATIVE); //very unstable
//cv::solvePnPRansac(points3d, points2d, cam_matrix, Mat(), rvec, tvec, false); // memory exception
//cv::solvePnP(points3d, points2d, cam_matrix, Mat(), rvec, tvec, false, CV_P3P); // memory exception
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've found what was the problems with СV_P3P flag. It's because I passed too many points there (exactly 4 is needed). Also for my case CV_EPNP flag for solvePnP works much more stable than with others, but still not that much. Ransac function should be free of this problem, but I cannot run it. It still crashes.

Comment: My solution for solvePnPRansac was to use Mat instead of vector. Though it is said in docs that both versions are possible, in my case Mat works ok, vector throws exception. I tried both double and float. 
By the way as expected Ransac is the most stable to outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was the problems with СV_P3P flag. It's because I passed too many points there (exactly 4 is needed).